# How can I use NLTK module on Atom Editor?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, atom-editor

I am very new at programming, so this problem much confuses me. 
On Atom Editor, when I typed
`from nltk.book import*`,
Error message was on display like this.
`ImportError: No module named nltk.book`

How can I solve this problem? I can use other modules such as `math` `urllib` `datetime`. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you don't have nltk or nltk.book in your system, or at least python can't find it. I don't know which operating system you are using, but I suggest to install nltk using pip. You can check the install instructions for nltk at http://www.nltk.org/install.html.